# find with -regex flag ti match files

Tags: regex, linux, find

under /tmp directory I have the following files

```
 file1
 file2
```

when I run the following find command with -regex , find command not match the files
why?

```
  find /tmp  -regex '/file(\d{1,3})/'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `man find` page:

> `-regex` pattern
>
> File name matches regular expression pattern.  This is a match on the whole path, not a search.  For example,  to match  a  file  named  `./fubar3`, you can use the regular expression `.*bar.` or `.*b.*3`, but not `f.*r3`.

Also, `\d` and `{m,n}` doesn't seem to be supported. The following works:

```
find /tmp -regex ".*file[0-9]+$"
```

Answer (score 0):

I asume it's unix.
     `find /tmp -type f -exec grep -il "whatever_you_want_in_file" {} \;`
which recursively searches for entries in the /tmp
but you probably want 
     `ls -a | grep file[0-9][0-9]?[0-9]?`
for /tmp only or
     `find /tmp -regexp "file[0-9][0-9]?[0-9]?"`
Not all the shells support \d as a one digit wild card, also the / is not necessary. I know it's used as assignments in Perl.